# How to solve this Python puzzle in a much more elegant manner?

Tags: coding-style, python

I was working through CoderByte 'Python' questions. Time is of essence, so the code may not be really readable but pretty straight forward. I will be interested in your approach. My code works for some words but testing with 'sentence' is giving me a different result, debugging as we speak. Please comment on my thinking!

**Question :**

Have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string. Use the Parameter Testing feature in the box below to test your code with different arguments. Do not modify the function name within the code. Do not put any code outside of the function and use the return keyword to return your answer from within the function.

**My code :**

```
def LetterChanges(str): 
    a = map(chr, range(97, 123))
    b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    b.remove('a')
    b.append('a')
    c = dict(zip(a,b))
    v = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

    k = str
    for i in range(len(str)):
        if str[i] in a:
            k = k.replace(str[i], c[str[i]])

    l = k
    for i in range(len(k)):
        if k[i] in v:
            l = l.replace(k[i], k[i].upper())

    print l

# this call is needed to test your function
# keep this when you submit your code
LetterChanges(str)
```

**Output :**

```
zddzst -> AEEAUU {wrong}!
sentence -> UfOUfOdf {wrong}!
```

Comment: `string.lowercase` is your friend.

Comment: "Time is of essence" Let me guess... is that because you get more points if someone gives you the correct answer quickly?

Comment: I submitted the code already! Now revising my solution cos' my solution looks stupid. If I am solving this for points, I wouldn't have posted this and waited for someone to answer! I said 'time is of essence' to thwart comments about my sloppy code!

Comment: is the input string fully lowercase?  Must the "shift" operation respect capitalization?

Comment: input string can be anything ex: Asdzxsss+++:* . Shift should indeed respect cap..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for this, it might look something like this:

```
import string

def LetterChanges(s):
    orig = string.letters
    new = string.ascii_lowercase[1:] + 'a' + string.ascii_uppercase[1:] + 'A'
    for vowel in 'aeiou':
        new = new.replace(vowel, vowel.upper())

    table = string.maketrans(orig, new)
    return s.translate(table)
```

Example:

```
>>> LetterChanges('sentence')
'tfOUfOdf'
```

For more efficiency, I would move the creation of `table` outside of the function so that it is only calculated once, instead of on each function call.  Alternatively just hard code the end values for `orig` and `new`, like this:

```
import string

def LetterChanges(s):
    t = string.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                         'bcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA')
    return s.translate(t)
```

**edit:** Here is a version that should work with coderbytes restrictions:

```
def LetterChanges(s):
    orig = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    new = 'bcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA'
    result = ''
    for c in s:
        if c in orig:
            c = new[orig.index(c)]
        result += c
    return result
```

Comment: It is coderbyte, I will have to check if it supports import statement. 'sorted()' was giving me an error and so was 'zip(a,b)'.

Comment: It says undefined module has no object 'maketrans'.

Comment: coderbyte is ridiculous.  Offer Python exercises, but neuter the language so you have to code it like it was Visual Basic...

Comment: Added a version that should work on coderbyte, and I definitely agree with Ned on coderbyte's restrictions!

Comment: Works fine! I wonder why CoderByte was doing that - to make us work harder without using the awesome one liners from Python?!

Comment: @ThinkCode - By the way, I think your original code might have worked fine, but instead of printing it you needed to return it.

Comment: F.J - CoderByte requires that I print rather than return. I kinda like the timed challenges but I don't understand why they don't like pythonic features in the tests.

Answer (score 2):

Just another solution

```
def LetterChanges(letters):
    """
    >>> LetterChanges('abcd')
    'bcdE'

    >>> LetterChanges('ABCD')
    'BCDE'

    >>> LetterChanges('sentence')
    'tfOUfOdf'
    """
    letter_map = {}
    changed_letters = []
    for old_letter in letters:
        if old_letter in letter_map:
            new_letter = letter_map[old_letter]
        else:
            ordinal = ord(old_letter)
            if 65 <= ordinal <= 90:    # ord('A'), ord('Z')
                new_letter = chr((ordinal - 64) % 26 + 65)
            elif 97 <= ordinal <= 122:    # ord('a'), ord('z')
                new_letter = chr((ordinal - 96) % 26 + 97)
            else:
                new_letter = old_letter

            if new_letter in 'aeiou':
                new_letter = new_letter.upper()
            letter_map[old_letter] = new_letter
        changed_letters.append(new_letter)
    return ''.join(changed_letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
sentence = <your sentence>
c = <your alphabet mapping>
v = <vowels>

def letterMap(x):
    letter = c[x]
    if letter in v:
        return letter.upper()
    else:
        return letter


letterList = map(letterMap, sentence)
answer = "".join(letterList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, passed all cases. The main part is to use the chr and ord to convert the alphabets and numbers back and forth in order to replace the current letter to the next one.

```
def LetterChanges(strParam):

  # code goes here
  result = ''
  for letter in strParam:
    if letter.isalpha():
        if letter != 'z':
            letter = chr(ord(letter)+1)
        else:
            letter = 'a'
    result+=letter

  result = ''.join(c.upper() if c in 'aeiou' else c for c in result)
  return result
```